# Customize AWStats Downloads

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, awstats, web-statistics

This seems ridiculous to me, but AWStats is not configured to count exe or dmg files as downloads.  What config file or setting can I change?  I tried looking through the documentation but found no mention of anything pertaining to Downloads.

I did find out to add another download section containing my file types here http://antezeta.com/news/awstats, but neither the hits or bandwidth calculations are even close to being correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra section to the end of the `awstats.config` file. The following example counts `*.dmg` files:

```
ExtraSectionName1="Disk Image Downloads" 
ExtraSectionCodeFilter1="200 304" 
ExtraSectionCondition1="URL,\.dmg" 
ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle1="File" 
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URL,(.*)"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnFormat1="%s"
ExtraSectionStatTypes1=HB
ExtraSectionAddAverageRow1=0
ExtraSectionAddSumRow1=1
MaxNbOfExtra1=100
MinHitExtra1=1
```

Bandwidth counted is unlikely to match file size times download count. Many downloads will not complete or will be interrupted.